# Load all classes and after that execute all existing {classname}::__initiation();

Tags: php, function, class

I want to do what's in the title. For example I include all files with my classes:

```
foreach(glob("library/*.php") as $file)
    include $file;
```

After that I have defined all my classes. Some of them have static function named for example **__initiation**. How to execute all of them after including? Something like here:

```
foreach( {classes} as $class ){
    if( function_exists( $class . '::__initiation' ) )
        $class::__initiation();
}
```

I want do it because some classes must be prepared (e.g. database connect) and some classes must use other classes. Often, in both directions (class named *foo* must use to initiation class named *bar*, and class named *bar* must use class named *foo*). Anyone know how to do it?
Example:

```
class database{
    // some stuff
    public static __initiation(){
        database::connect();
        foo::bar();
    }
}
class foo{
    // some stuff
    public static bar(){/* blah blah blah */}
    public static __initiation(){
        database::select(/* blah blah blah */);
        foo::start();
    }
}

// Execute all declared {classname}::__initiation() function right now.
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Can't you, just after you include `$file`, do `$file::__initiation();`? If you've named your classes as per your php files, this should work (after you've manually removed the extension, of course).

Comment: @D4V1D But if $file::__initiation(); uses yet undeclared class? That's why I want to do it after included all files. And not always the class called as files.

Comment: Don't get it. How can `$file::_initiation()` uses yet undeclared class as `$file` would be the name of the class being `include`d? Can you post a sample of one of the class code you're trying to `include`?

Comment: @D4V1D I added example code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem you will run into, is that the files are listet in alphabetic order. But the dependencies between them, are not in this order, e.g. bar references foo, foo is not loaded yet, when bar is loaded.

Do you know the __autoload functionality? Here is my AutoLoader class, that could help you:

```
<?php
namespace de\g667\util;

class AutoLoader
{
    /**
     * Registers the autoload-function. All needed classes and interfaces will be
     * automatically loaded on demand.
     */
    static function register() {
        spl_autoload_register(
        function ($class) {
            $class = str_replace ("\\", "/", $class);
            $cwd = getcwd();
            $filepath = $class.'.php';
            $path = PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filepath;
            if( ! file_exists($path) ){
                error_log("Autoloading $class failed");
            }
            require_once $path;
        }
        );
    }

    static function setPath($path) {
        define("PATH", $path);
    }
}
?>
```

Save this code in /library/de/g667/AutoLoader.php

Use of the AutoLoader:

```
  <?php
  require_once 'library/de/g667/util/AutoLoader.php';

  use de\g667\util\AutoLoader;

  AutoLoader::setPath("/path/to/library");
  AutoLoader::register();
  ?>
```

Be aware to have one file for each class in you libraryFolder. Insert your instantiate funcion in the AutoLoader, then you should be able to easily instantiate your classes.

Comment: I can use it but is not a solution for my problem. I must include all of classes and next execute all starting functions looking like: `{classname}::__initiation();`. Look at my question, I added a simple example.

Comment: Now I got it: get_declared_classes( ) gives you the array of all your classes after you included them. But for more complex projects, it could be overload to include every php file all the time, so the dynamic loading with __autoload() could be a good alternativ.

Comment: `get_declared_classes( ) ` is awesome. I can't find something like it. Thanks a lot :>

Comment: That's not right, you found the dynamic way in my post above ;-) One time used, you will never miss it, because including and requiring files is nevermore necessary.